# Moto G 1st Gen - Mobile Data not working after upgrade to 5.0.2

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, mobile-data, motorola-moto-g

After upgrading to Lollipop from 4.4.4, mobile data doesn't work. I have tried all the solutions listed in various forums including,
1. Reboot
2. Reboot after re-inserting the sim card.
3. Manually add the APN (Got the settings from the service provider)
4. Toggle between the Preferred Network type (2G and 3G)

I have only one usable sim slot, and so cannot use sim slot-1. I have heard it worked for a few guys after putting the sim in the other slot, but unfortunately I cannot try that out.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Okay, so here I am posting an answer to my own question. 
I finally visited a Motorola service center today to get the problem fixed and I was told that they are aware of the issue and that they'll be rolling out an update with a fix in 5 days.
Hopefully everything will turn out well after that.

Comment: Just yesterday i got lollipop on my MotoG! I'm having same issue!! Its been 4 months since you posted the answer; Did the update roll out? Is your mobile data working?

Comment: @neckTwi: It looks like Rocks may never return. Did you ever find a solution to this issue which started affecting you more than a year ago?