# VS98523c updated successfully but 4G Data doesn't work

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, lg-g3

The 4G connection is there but I can't use it.

I went into the Mobile Networks to check the signal strength and there is a 4G signal, but the phone doesn't want to use that connection for data.

- I am not roaming
- Mobile Data is turned on

  - I turned it off and then on again twice with no results.
- I switched the "System Select" to all the options and no results

  - default was global - didn't work.
- Airplane mode is turned off
- I am able to make phone calls

What other troubleshooting steps are there?

Is this a known issue and is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

after the 3rd or 4th reboot the 4G data now functions again.  sounds like other phones and other versions were having this issue as well.

[Cellular data not working since 5.1 Lollipop flash](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/106238/52568)

[How do I get my mobile data to work again, after the new Android 5.1 update?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/105520/52568)

[Nexus 5 upgraded to 5.1 and mobile data wont work anymore](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/103316/52568)

[Moto G 1st Gen - Mobile Data not working after upgrade to 5.0.2](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/97591/52568)